# How should I protect my Database when I provide totally offline Android app?

Tags: android

I made the offline dictionary(local langauge) and it includes nearly 1 million words.

When I upload it to play store any one can get the APK file and then they can extract it and they can find the DB. Then they can get the total database withing just a few minute.

Even I give this app as free, I don't like someone to get the **whole database within few minutes** because I took many years to build this database.

So how can I protect my DB, but I need to give the app as offline app?

Comment: Encrypt the words stored in your database so even if they obtain your local sqlite file, it would be hard for them to Decrypt the information.

Comment: Rather than encrypting your words, you can encrypt your database like mydb.db.crypt.

Comment: @Enzokie  I need to use something like hash because I have to use Two-way encryption... I have to write that logic also inside the app. So checking the code, other also can find the decrypt method and they can decrypt all words... Am I right?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson I personally believe that reverse engineering an obfuscated APK is not an easy thing so it is unlikely to obtain the exact source code of the app.   And in reality no such thing as perfect software however doing the above steps decreases the chance of information breach :)